# Angular seems to build dev dependencies into universal bundle?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering, angular-webpack

I'm using typegoose to unify my interfaces + db schemas shared across ~6 apps. It helps me keep my data structure consistent.

Now that means that most of my types/interfaces in my Angular app are coming from an [external project.](https://github.com/michaelbats/tlabs-models)

Because of this I have:

```
    "typegoose": "^5.9.0",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.17",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.12",
    "@tlabs/models": "^1.7.13",
```

added as dev dependencies. All works fine and I can even build but when I try to build using universal, I can see this warning:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js 11:28-64
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

x5 times about mongodb/mongoose

And when I check my lambda function log, I can see:

```
2019-09-17T14:56:59.691Z undefined ERROR (node:8) DeprecationWarning: This Package got moved, please use `@hasezoey/typegoose` | github:hasezoey/typegoose
```

which comes from typegoose so that gets me confused.

I'm 100% using only as types, if I attempt to use it by instantiating a class object using one of the types, the whole app won't work at all.

Is there something I'm missing about the configuration of webpack here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got similar errors when dealing with angular universal and other SQL databases. But, there is a solution that at least worked for me.

And that is the `webpack-node-externals` package. Which simply makes webpack ignore your node_modules folder.

Link to the NPM page >> https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals

assuming everything else in your `webpack.server.config.js` this should solve those errors and make your bundle size much much smaller. (keep in mind that you will need to include your node_modules folder when deploying to other environments)

Brief Tutorial

1. `npm i webpack-node-externals`
2. open `webpack.server.config.js` in a text editor
3. Format that file to look similar to this:

```
module.exports = env => {
  return {
    mode: "production",
    entry: {
      // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
      server: "./server.ts"
    },
    externals: {
      "./dist/server/main": 'require("./server/main")'
    },
    target: "node",
    node: {
      __dirname: false,
      __filename: false
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // <======LOOK HERE======|
    resolve: { extensions: [".ts", ".js"] },
    optimization: {
      minimize: false
    },
    output: {
      // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
      path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
      noParse: /polyfills-.*\.js/,
      rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
        {
          // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
          // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
          test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
          parser: { system: true }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
        /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
        path.join(__dirname, "src"), // location of your src
        {} // a map of your routes
      ),
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
        /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
        path.join(__dirname, "src"),
        {}
      ),
    ]
  };
};
```